# How to check duplication of a value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to store a `localStorage` value only once. If it exists in, `localStorage`, an alert should appear.

Comment: `if ( localStorage.getItem('something') ) { alert(); } else { store(); }`

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(localStorage.getItem('item') != null){
   alert('in localStorage');
}
else{
   alert('not in localStorage');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's fairly simple.

Just check to see whether the key exists in localStorage and add it if it doesn't:

```
if(localStorage["keyName"]){
    alert("The key is stored");
}else{
    localStorage["keyName"] = "value";
}
```